# Togglz feature state change notification

Tags: java, featuretoggle, togglz

I have two application  - `api` and `dashboard`. Both of these applications use the same Features from the same database. Togglz console is only active in `dashboard` application. The issue is that when I change the state of the feature in my `dashboard` application, `api` application is not immediately aware about that. I need to restart my `api` in order to refresh the features state.

Is it possible to notify `api` application about changes of feature state without restarting?

**UPDATED - Togglz configuration added**

This is the a base configuration in my Maven `common` project(`api` and `dashboard` projects depend on this one):

```
@Configuration
public class FeatureToggleConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    public FeatureManager getFeatureManager() {
        // @formatter:off
        FeatureManager featureManager = new FeatureManagerBuilder()
            .stateRepository(new CachingStateRepository(new JDBCStateRepository(dataSource)))
            .featureEnum(ApplicationFeatures.class)
            .userProvider(new SpringSecurityUserProvider(Authority.Type.ROLE_ADMIN.getName()))
            .build();
        // @formatter:on
        return featureManager;
    }

}
```

`ApplicationFeatures`(also placed in `common` project):

```
public enum ApplicationFeatures implements Feature {

    // @formatter:off
    @EnabledByDefault
    @Label("Log Events Feature")
    LOG_EVENT_FEATURE,

    @EnabledByDefault
    @Label("Log Ok Sessions Feature")
    LOG_OK_SESSIONS_FEATURE,

    @EnabledByDefault
    @Label("Log HTTP Requests Data Feature")
    LOG_HTTP_REQUESTS_DATA_FEATURE;
    // @formatter:on

    public boolean isActive() {
        return FeatureContext.getFeatureManager().isActive(this);
    }

}
```

This is `DashboardFeatureToggleConfiguration`(for Togglz web console) from my `dashboard` project:

```
@Configuration
public class DashboardFeatureToggleConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean getTogglzConsole() {
        ServletRegistrationBean servlet = new ServletRegistrationBean();
        servlet.setName("TogglzConsole");
        servlet.setServlet(new TogglzConsoleServlet());
        servlet.setUrlMappings(Collections.singletonList("/togglz/*"));
        return servlet;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please include your full Togglz configuration?

Comment: @chkal I have added my configuration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `CachingStateRepository` which is causing the problem your are describing. You have basically two options:

First you could remove the `CachingStateRepository` and use `JDBCStateRepository` directly. This way you will have much more hits on the database but this may be acceptable. So your configuration would look like this:

```
.stateRepository(new JDBCStateRepository(dataSource))
```

Our you could specify the TTL value for the `CachingStateRepository` which means that the cached entries will be cached only for a specific time:

```
.stateRepository(
   new CachingStateRepository(new JDBCStateRepository(dataSource), 10000)
)
```

In this example the TTL is set to 10000 which means that the feature state will only be cached for 10 seconds.